# Weight lifting in a very small space

Tags: weightlifting

My only option is to lift in a bedroom; there are are no other options than this room.

The room contains a double bed and nothing else. There is enough space on three side of the bed to walk around it, but not much more. The bed stands against one wall, and I would very much prefer not to move it to be against two, to gain space on the other side, as there are things under the bed which would no longer be accessible and it's a heavy bed, which is not so easy to shove around (yes, I realize the irony :-) ).

I have a straight barbell, an EZ-curl bar and some dumb-bell handles, plus rubber coated plates which fit them.

There is room to curl the EZ-curl bar, but not, for instance to squat or do push ups.

What exercises can I do ***safely***, on or by the bed, in such limited space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your lack of space, and, the proper environment for training, I would **not** consider using an ez-bar or any other form of equipment.  Your current situation, in my opinion, is not conducive to obtaining an efficient work out and you run the risk of injury and damaging things in the room.   Rather than looking to use an ez-curl bar, etc., you should consider body weight movements until such time as you have sufficient space to train effectively.  For example, using resistance bands and the bed, you should be able to train most large body parts.  It may require you to be creative, but, you should be able to get an effective work out.